# Show div while code is equal to given text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code at the  minute that is wrong. I want to show div `lds-roller` while the text in `id = searchFor` is equal to `_`

```js
(function() {

  if ($("#searchFor").text() === "_") {
    $('.lds-roller').show();
  }
})();
```

```
<div class="lds-roller"><div></div><div></div><div>
</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
 <p>
     <span class=""> 

      <span class="">
             <a href="{% pageurl post %}#disqus_thread" id="searchFor"> _
            </a>
      </span>
   </span>
 </p>
```

It seems like after like 10 seconds there is an HTTP response to change `_` to `1` for example. I want `lds-roller` to not be visible post when this happens.

```
.lds-roller {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;

}
```

Comment: The text of `#searchFor` is changed via code, right?

Comment: Yeah changes from `_` on getting information from another page

Comment: I added snippet to your post, it working fine

Comment: check my answer.. Just add css display block. it will work fine

Answer (score 4):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   if ($("#searchFor").text() === "_") 
   {
       $('.lds-roller').css('display','block');
   }
});
```

The ready() method is used to make a function available after the document is loaded. Whatever code you write inside the $(document ).ready() method will run once the page DOM is ready to execute JavaScript code.

**Full answer**

```
<style>
    .lds-roller {
        display: none
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchFor">dsfds_</div>
<div class="lds-roller">Hi I'm lds-roller!</div>

<script>
    (function() {
          if ($("#searchFor").text() === "_") {
            $('.lds-roller').css('display','block');
          }
        })();
</script>
```

Comment: Didnt work unfortunately :( Just wasnt displaying the div at all

Comment: Nice, but read the edited question and question title. OP wants to keep showing the div as long as the content of `searchFor` is "_", and then hide it when it isn't anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of jQuery [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function to trigger the input field change.

If the change event is not a keyboard input event, you can make use of [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event of jQuery. The main disadvantage of using this is if you are going for a keyboard event, this wont reflect until you are blured from your input field or hitting the enter key.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchFor").keyup(function() {
    // $("#searchFor").change will also work 
    if ($("#searchFor").val() === "_") {
      $(".lds-roller").show();
    } else {
      $(".lds-roller").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.lds-roller {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Press "_" and see the hidden button</p>

<input type="text" id="searchFor" />

<button class="lds-roller">hidden button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#searchFor").text() == "_") 
  {
   $('.lds-roller').removeClass('lds-roller');
  }
 });

or


 $(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#searchFor").text() == "_") 
  {
  $('.lds-roller').css('display','block');
  }
 });
```

Comment: do you want to show the div?for showing,removeClass will work

Comment: Ive revised my question to make it easier to understand. I want `.lds-roller` to only be `visible` while the text is `_` in `#searchFor`.

Comment: Did you change it?

Comment: both of my code   will diplay div if the text in #searchFor is  _

Answer (score 0):

You say you want something to happen *while* something else is equal to something. This implies either a polled timer to check on that status or an event to be the trigger. You could register an event listener for `onchange` of `searchFor` however you will also need an `else` to your handler to hide the element when the condition of underscore is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, your text changes after some HTTP request (or similar).

So, one approach would be to first show the div once the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lds-roller').show(); //initially, show the div
});
```

Then, in your callback function that changes the value of `#searchFor`, add the following line to hide the div:

```
$('.lds-roller').hide(); //the info is now retrieved, hide the div
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) object to fire an event whenever the contents of your div (`#searchFor`) has changed. This may be overkill for this problem though.